# Использование или использованием?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, падежи

Приоритетной и актуальной задачей считаем дальнейшее поступательное наращивание совместных усилий в эффективной борьбе с такими глобальными вызовами, как терроризм, экстремизм, транснациональная организованная преступность, а также использование**м** Интернета в террористических и экстремистских целях.

Нужна ли тут буква "м" и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без этой буквы добавляет предложению ложные смыслы: a) использование Интернета в недобрых целях является частью актуальной задачи и б) такое использование Интернета - один из упомянутых "вызовов", *наравне* с самим терроризмом. Логично было бы написать "***с*** использование**м**": повторение предлога вносит ясность относительно того, *с чем ещё* (или в частности) предлагается бороться.

Answer (score 1):

[а та́кже](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-2441.htm), *союз*
Употребляется при присоединении однородного члена предложения, который — являясь добавочным — отграничивается от другого или от ряда других однородных членов; **и**.

Если Вы относите *использование Интернета в террористических и экстремистских целях* к глобальным вызовам, то возникает такой однородный ряд:
терроризм, экстремизм, транснациональная организованная преступность, а также (**= и**) использование Интернета в террористических и экстремистских целях.

Думаю, что наиболее вероятен другой смысловой вариант — эффективная **борьба** (с чем?) **с  глобальными вызовами, а также** (= и) (с чем?) **с использованием** Интернета в террористических и экстремистских целях. В этом случае — для однозначного восприятия громоздкого предложения — его, мне кажется, надо перестроить.

Приоритетной и актуальной задачей считаем дальнейшее поступательное наращивание совместных усилий в эффективной борьбе с глобальными вызовами, такими как терроризм, экстремизм, транснациональная организованная преступность, а также с использованием Интернета в террористических и экстремистских целях.

Comment: Проблема с другим предполагаемым смыслом в том, что ряд "вызовов" - _неоднородный_: использование Интернета для в целях терроризма - "вызов" меньшего порядка (элемент "вспоможения" терроризму перечислением денег, передачей тактической информации и т. п.), чем сам терроризм как элемент перечисления. Передача такого смысла была бы стилистически неудачной - дело не только в _меньшей вероятности_.